# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS libraries

Tags: ros, makefile, library

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I would like to add ROS support to my own software. What libraries do I add in my makefile?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9242/ros-libraries/) by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 528 on 2011-02-28

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-02**:
And others you can also update your answers as aswin updates his question.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-03-02**:
aswin, please update your question instead of replying in answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best place to start for understanding how to integrate with ROS is to go through the [ROS tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials)  They will help you learn how to use ROS and what ROS provides.  Once you have that understanding adding ROS to your existing code should be relatively easy.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may need to install ROS first.
And use "roscreate-pkg pkg_name std_msgs rospy roscpp" to create basic package using ros libraries.
If you want to edit in makefile,
use cmake (CMakeLists.txt) in your project.

---

Originally posted by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) with karma: 2570 on 2011-02-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I think the following should do. Building your own files as a library and then linking it.

rosbuild_add_library(Util src/libTF.cpp src/Pose3DCache.cpp src/Pose3D.cpp)
rosbuild_add_executable(testTF src/test/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(testTF Util)

Thanks

---

Originally posted by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) with karma: 528 on 2011-03-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4